# Why does Python-Requests return the same data when issuing POST in a loop even after closing sessions?

Tags: python-2.7, http, python-requests

I'm using Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) but need to issue requests/POST to a SOAP API endpoint. However, I keep receiving the same response for multiple requests, even though I rebuild a new request in a loop. I've tried closing sessions/responses to no avail.

Manually issuing a request returns different data. What may I be missing?

Here's a sample of the code:

```
quoteVariables = """
<QuoteVariables>
 {0}
</QuoteVariables>"""

for state, zipcode in states.iteritems():
    for key, value in buckets.iteritems():

        quotesXMLWithStateZip = buildQuote() #returns long xml string
        quotes = quoteVariables.format(quotesXMLWithStateZip)
        soapRequest=soapXML.format(state, quotes, value)

        headers = {'content-Type':'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'SOAPAction':'http://my.url.com', 'Connection':'close'} 

        with requests.Session() as s:
            response = s.post('https://my.url.com/endpoint', headers=headers, data=soapRequest, stream=False)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                xml = xmltodict.parse(response.text)

                #fetch relevant part of xml resposne, ignore soap headers etc.,

            else:
                print "Failure! Status: "+response.status_code+" Reason: "+response.reason

            response.close()
            s.close()

        #reset xml stuff to prevent stale data from lying around owing to string sharing/copying
        quotesXMLWithStateZip = ""
        quotes = ""
        soapRequest = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly moving this code into a separate *class* seems to solve the problem - my guess is something with globals/states seems to throw off the python-requests module (I could be wrong).

Also, moving to a class, the `with` block becomes optional i.e., whether it exists or not doesn't seem to matter - the code works as expected with/without it.

For example:

```
responses = {}
for state, zipcode in states.iteritems():
    for key, value in buckets.iteritems():
        fetcher = MyFetcher()
        responses[state] = fetcher.getQuotes(state, zipcode, key, value)
print responses
```

The code of `MyFetcher` looks something like:

```
class MyFetcher:
    def getQuotes(self, state, zipcode, key, value):
        quotesXMLWithStateZip = self.buildQuote() #returns long xml string
        quotes = self.quoteVariables.format(quotesXMLWithStateZip)
        soapRequest=self.soapXML.format(state, quotes, value)

        headers = {'content-Type':'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'SOAPAction':'http://my.url.com', 'Connection':'close'} 

        with requests.Session() as s: # <- ENTIRELY OPTIONAL
            response = s.post('https://my.url.com/endpoint', headers=headers, data=soapRequest, stream=False)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                xml = xmltodict.parse(response.text)

                #fetch relevant part of xml resposne, ignore soap headers etc.,

                return parsedResponse

            else:
                print "Failure! Status: "+response.status_code+" Reason: "+response.reason
                return None

            response.close() # <- NOT NEEDED
            s.close()        # <- NOT NEEDED
```

I can only guess globals causing a problem somehow with the act of building/sending a request and/or receiving a response.

Comment: YEARS LATER, but dude you are a godsend. This worked for me too.